# How can I run python scripts on my webserver?

Tags: python, apache2

I have a test script, /var/www/etym/cgi-bin/test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"

print "Hello World!"
```

And I'm trying to run it by going to `http://localhost/etym/cgi-bin/test.py` in my browser, but it's not working--Firefox just asks me whether I'd like to open the file with gedit or save it to the disk. What do I need to do to get it to run? I already ran `chmod +x` on the script.

Comment: Could you explain what your requirements are? Most people use `wsgi` for Python nowadays or simply a framework to build the applications in. Do you really need to do it plain CGI or...? And what web server are you using? (You probably don't want to run one, or you want a wsgi module for you web server.)

Comment: I just want to be able to run a simple python script on a web server. I'm just using the standard apache2 that comes with ubuntu and the stock configuration. I don't know the difference between cgi and wsgi, and so I'm not married to CGI, but I don't want to have to configure a big framework, apache modules, or other complicated things just to be able to see "Hello World" in my browser window.

Comment: You can try flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart) for simple python "hello world" web scripts.

Comment: "/var/www/etym/cgi-bin/test.py" please put those files OUTSIDE your webroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have configured your webserver properly to run CGI scripts.

Refer this for more info: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

Answer (score 0):

this could help if the link doesnt yet solve the problem  (tried on Ubuntu 14.04)

Check loaded modules with:

```
   apache2ctl -M
```

Look for:

```
  cgid_module (shared)
```

If it's not loaded, load it with:

```
  a2enmod cgid
```

Restart apache and then refresh browser